# Use send() functions to send numbers to __isoc99_scanf("%d", &number)

Tags: python, c, ctf, pwntools

I am trying to solve a pwn problem in a ctf platform. The program only uses `scanf()` to get index and content of a number array from standard input:

```
for ( i = 0; i <= 3; ++i )                    
{
  puts("enter index:");
  __isoc99_scanf("%d", &index);
  if ( index > 3 )
  {
    puts("index is too big");
    exit(0);
  }
  puts("enter value:");
  __isoc99_scanf("%d", &num);
  s[index] = num;
}

while ( j <= 3 )
  printf("0x%08x\t", s[j++]);

return __readgsdword(0x14u) ^ canary;
```

However, when I use `send()` function to send 4 bytes int number to the program, the scanf functions seem to detect EOF (rather than the 4-bytes int number) and scanf nothing. Moreover, the following `scanf()` rejects to get numbers because of the EOF. My `send()` statements and executing results are as follow:

```
r.recv()
r.sendline(p32(0x1))
r.recv()
r.sendline(p32(0x1))
```

[exceptional executing results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0aos.png)

My question is: How to explain this exceptional problem, and how to correctly use `send()` to send numbers to `__isoc99_scanf("%d", &number)` functions in this program?

Comment: You appear to be sending a 4-byte little-endian binary number to the program, not a text string that can be parsed as a number by `scanf`.  Are you sure that's what you should be doing?

Comment: Yes, thank you @zwol. I didn't notice the way in which `scanf` parse the input.